# mysql conditional join / search-replace

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables like that:

**movies**

```
id | value
-------------
1  | 10
2  | 11
3  | 12
4  | 13
```

**actors**

```
id | movie_value |type   | value
-------------------------------
1  |  10         | movie  | 21
2  |  11         | movie  | 22
3  |  12         | movie  | 23
4  |  13         | series | 13
```

There is not relationship between movies and actors, I know its weird. And I want to convert movies table's "movie_id" like that. 
Conditional row = type / movie.

**movie**

```
id | movie_id 
-------------
1  | 21
2  | 22
3  | 23
4  | 13
```

Some sort of search/replace in numbers. Is this possible on MySql?

My query which is not working:

```
UPDATE movies
INNER JOIN actors ON movies.value = actors.movie_value AND actors.type='movie'
SET id = actors.value
```

Comment: since both actors and movies have the field ID, wouldn't the engine get confused to the ambiguity as to what ID you're wanting to update (in other words shouldn't ID be `movies.id`?

Comment: Yes, its confused. But dont have relationship between movies and actors. I want match movies.value = actors.movie_value and replace same ID's to movie.movie_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 UPDATE  movies m
 INNER JOIN actors a ON m.value = a.movie_value 
 SET m.`value` = a.`value` 
 WHERE a.type='movie'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d528/1)

in your query you forgot WHERE clause.

Comment: Does he actually care about `actors.type` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE movies, actors
SET movies.id = actors.value
WHERE movies.value = actors.movie_value AND actors.type LIKE 'movie%'
```

Comment: @gnoxis I guess the problem is in type column. I did small update.

Answer (score 0):

first of all welcome to Stackoverflow (:
Since an actor can be related to many movies and series, and a movie or serie has many actors, I would suggest you to use agregation. Here are some approaches,

---

[image: Diagram1]
This example (in my humble opinion) makes things more clear, allowing you to define specific characteristics to series and movies; actors here can also act on both movies and series.

---

[image: Diagram2]
This one is quite simple and summarizes movies and series information in one table. Particularities would be stored in partition tables if necessary.

---

I have the entire script if you want any.
Maybe it is not exactly your goal, in this case you should not forget to explicitly indicate every field's table. Since you're dealing with two tables, mysql wouldn't know where a certain column (in your example, *id*) came from.

Regards,

Leonardo